# How to inflate different layout using same recycle adapter?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using wordAdapter class to recycle list view i want to inflate different layout on a give condition like if flag is equal to one than inflate activity_all layout and if flag is equal to two than inflate activity_food layout but when i try to use the following code my app get crashed

```
 CountingActivity countingActivity;
    FoodActivity foodActivity;
    //Making constructor of the class wordAdapter which takes Activity and ArrayList as arguments
    public wordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<word> words,int flag){
        super(context,0,words);
    }

    @NonNull

    public View getView(int position,@NonNull View convertView,@NonNull ViewGroup parent){

        View listItemView = convertView;

        //Checking if recycle view is available or not
         if(listItemView == null)
        {
            if (countingActivity.flag == 1) {
                listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_all,parent,false);

            }
            else if(foodActivity.flag == 2)
            {
                listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_food,parent,false);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add this in [**`onCreateViewHolder`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup,%20int)) section

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public YouAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        if (viewType == 0)
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_xml_one, parent, false);
            return new v;

        }else
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_xml_two, parent, false);
            return new v;
        }

    }
```

Comment: For more information visit https://www.journaldev.com/12372/android-recyclerview-example

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class, you need to declare the type on the top like

```
private static final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
private static final int LOADING = 0;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY = 2;
```

And in the `onCreateViewHolder` you need to declare the ViewHolders like this

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                      int viewType) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = null;

        switch (viewType) {

            case VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY:
                View emptyView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.item_view_no_data, parent, false);

                vh = new EmptyViewHolder(emptyView);
                break;

            case VIEW_ITEM:
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.item_view_game_details, parent, false);

                vh = new GameViewHolder(itemView);
                break;

            case LOADING:
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.layout_progress_bar, parent, false);

                vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
                break;

        }

        return vh;
    }
```

And in `onBindViewHolder` you need to first check the instance of viewholder and the typecast according to the instance

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if (holder instanceof GameViewHolder) {
           /** You code for you ViewHlder**/

        } else if (holder instanceof ProgressViewHolder) {
            /** You code for you ViewHlder
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            **/
        }
    }
```